# Formatting a string for Python c-type structure and substructure

Tags: python, parsing, hex, structure, ctypes

I get a traceback whenever the string function in main_structure starts parsing the info in sub_structure. I got a TypeError saying, "not all my arguments were converted during string formatting." In another attempt, I got a TypeError saying, "%X format: a number is required, not sub_structure." I was able to successfully parse all other fields before including sub_structure in the main_structure fields.

```
new_sys = 0xFE

class sub_structure(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [ ("Block", c_uint16),
                 ("Count", c_uint32)
               ]

    def __str__(self):
        retStr = ""
        retStr += "Block: %8.8Xh\n" % self.Block
        retStr += "Count: %8.8Xh\n" % self.Count

        return retStr

class main_structure(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [ ("System", c_uint8 * total),
                 ("Erase", c_uint32),
                 ("Global", c_uint32),
                 ("Offset", c_uint32),
                 ("Start", c_uint16),
                 ("SysCnt", sub_structure * 6)
               ]

    def __str__(self):
        retstr = "Parsing Buffer Data:\n"
        for idx, sys in enumerate(self.System):
            sysStr = "0x%d" % sys
            if sys == new_sys:
                sysStr = "0 -- (New System)"
            retstr += "System[" + str(idx) + "]: " + sysStr + "\n"
            retstr += "Erase: 0x%08X\n" % self.Erase
            retstr += "Global: 0x%08X\n" % self.Global
            retstr += "Offset: 0x%08X\n" % self.Offset
        for idx, itm in enumerate(self.SysCnt):
            retstr += "SysCnt%d: 0x%08X\n" % (idx, itm)
        return retstr
```

Comment: `retstr += "SysCnt%d: 0x%08X\n" % (idx, itm)`. `%08X` expects an integral type while you're passing an instance (`itm`). What exactly do you want to have there? Hint: replace `0x%08X` by `%s`, and you'll get what `itm.__str__()` returns.

Comment: @CristiFati
The spec I am following shows that Block goes from index 0 - 5. and Count has index 0 - 5. In the buffer, I am reading from, they alternate like, "Block 0 = 0x8, Count 0 = 0x2, Block 1 = 0x6, Count 1 = 0xB, Block 2 = 0x6, Count 1 = 0x2 ...etc" That is why I created sub_structure to help parse them instead of listing them in main_structure 6 times each. Because doing that would achieve the right result, but it isn't as clean.

Comment: Yes, agree, but that's not relevant here. Maybe my question wasn't clear enough: what do you want tho have returned there (I meant by `0x%08X`)? What properties of each `sub_structure` entry do you want to be returned by the current method (`main_structure.__str__`)? Also did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @CristiFati I tested your suggestion to use `%s` and it works! Now that there is no traceback, I am able to continue with this project. Thank you so much!